# planarity of a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

If I have a quadrilateral in $\mathbb{R}^3$, is it true that the quadrilateral is simple and planar if and only if the interior angles sum to $2\pi$?

I'm sure this fact is very elementary, but some searching didn't turn up a proof.

Comment: I think a more precise statement is that the angle-sum is $2\pi$ if and only if it’s a planar quadrilateral without self-intersection.

Comment: I’m not a geometer at all, but I think this is a really interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is spherical geometry's Triangle Inequality: Given three rays emanating from a point, *any one of the angles formed is less than, or equal to, the sum of the other two* (and the "equal to" case corresponds to the rays being coplanar).

To apply this fact to your question, let $ABCD$ be the quadrilateral, which we decompose into triangle by drawing diagonal $AC$. Then we manipulate the angle-sums of those triangles:

$$\begin{align}
2\pi &= (\angle B + \angle BAC + \angle BCA) + (\angle D + \angle DAC + \angle DCA)\\
&= (\angle BAC + \angle DAC) + \angle B + (\angle BCA + \angle DCA) + \angle D \\
&\ge \phantom{(\angle BAC}\angle A\phantom{\angle DAC} + \angle B + \phantom{(\angle BCA}\angle C\phantom{\angle DCA} + \angle D
\end{align}$$

We get $\angle A = \angle BAC + \angle DAC$ when, and only when, $\overrightarrow{AB}$, $\overrightarrow{AC}$, $\overrightarrow{AD}$ are coplanar (similarly for $\angle C = \angle BCA + \angle DCA$), which is to say that the quadrilateral itself is coplanar. Done.

---

I'll point out that the sophisticated version of the Triangle Inequality is the [Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines); for instance, writing $\theta$ for the dihedral angle along $AC$, the angles at vertex $A$ satisfy ...

$$\cos\angle A = \cos\angle BAC \cos\angle DAC + \sin\angle BAC \sin\angle DAC \cos\theta$$

We get the Triangle Inequality by observing that $-1 \le \cos\theta \le 1$ implies

$$\cos(\angle BAC + \angle DAC) \le \cos\angle A \le \cos(\angle BAC - \angle DAC)$$

so that 
$$|\angle BAC - \angle DAC| \le \angle A \le \angle BAC + \angle DAC$$

Note that equality occurs for $\cos\theta = \pm 1$, whereupon the triangles on either side of $AC$ are "opened" or "folded" *flat*: they're coplanar.

In Euclidean geometry, the same thinking takes us from

$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b \cos C$$

to

$$(a-b)^2 \le c^2 \le (a+b)^2$$

to the Euclidean Triangle Inequality:

$$|a-b| \le c \le a+b$$

Answer (score 0):

Without restriction of generality you may assume two consecutive vertices at $x_0:=(0,0,0)$ and $x_1:=(1,0,0)$. Then $x_2=(1,a,b)$ with $a^2+b^2>0$ and $x_3=(0,c,d)$ with $c^2+d^2>0$. It follows that $x_2-x_3=(1,a-c,b-d)$ and therefore
$$0=(x_3-x_0)\cdot(x_2-x_3)=c(a-c)+d(b-d)\ ;$$
and similarly
$$0=(x_2-x_1)\cdot(x_2-x_3)=a(a-c)+b(b-d)\ .$$
Subtracting the last two equations we obtain
$$(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2=0\ ,$$
which implies $a=c$ and $b=d$. It follows that our four points are $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, $(1,a,b)$, and $(0,a,b)$; so they are the vertices of a planar rectangle.

Comment: I see how you can rotate and scale the quadrilateral to position $x_0, x_1, x_2$ as you say... but why does $x_3$ have first coordinate 0? Also, why must those dot products be zero?